# Opencv warp perspective

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I want to figure out how warp perspective function works in opencv.
How that function find our area of interest using reference image and 3x3 matrix
and which file i have to look on github.

Answer (score 1):

Formula is here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp#L2749

For each image pixel with coordinates (x, y) calculates a new coordinates: (x* y* 1) = (x y 1) * Homo, where Homo - 3x3 matrix.

And the current pixel value goes to the new coordinates (x*, y*). After makes spaces interpolation and borders processing.